# What is the correct notation for "for all nonzero $a$ in the real numbers"?

Tags: notation, article-writing

> For all nonzero $a$ in the real numbers,...

Which, or neither, is the correct notation for the above quantification?

$\forall a \in \mathbb{R} \neq 0,\ldots$

$\forall a \neq 0 \in \mathbb{R},\ldots$

Comment: $\forall a \in \mathbb R (a \ne 0)$

Comment: Is there a reason this has to be all symbolic? Why not just say "For each nonzero real number $a$" and then continue with what comes next?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro No, it could perfectly be written non-symbolically, but I had thought to do so. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither would be particularly great.

The first seems to come with the additional implication that $\mathbb{R} \ne 0$, and the second does not necessarily imply that $a \in \mathbb{R}$, just that $0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \ne 0$.

---

For something like this, it would be best to write
$$
\forall a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}
$$
since $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ is the set of nonzero reals. I have a tendency to write
$$
\forall a \in \mathbb{R}_{\ne 0}
$$
since it is more compact, but this has a prerequisite of ensuring this is a well-defined notation (since it is somewhat infrequent in my experience). Another more common notation is
$$
\forall a \in \mathbb{R}^\times \text{ or } \forall a \in \mathbb{R}^\ast
$$
where $F^\times$ or $F^\ast$ can denote the invertible elements of a field (i.e. its nonzero elements).

---

Or, frankly, you could just write "for all real, nonzero $a$" in plain English; no one would reasonably take issue with this outside of very narrow contexts, and it's perfectly clear. Math communication isn't just about writing down a mess of symbols, after all; to communicate effectively, plain English is useful too, especially if the thing you want to state mathematically is (frankly) clunky in symbolic language.

Comment: And would $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}: a\neq 0$ be correct?

Comment: Depends on the context. And even perhaps in that context, it might be technically correct, but it might not be a great way of phrasing things.

Comment: @AntonioDeAngelis If `∀a∈R: a≠0` is a full sentence, then it can only mean "every real $a$ is nonzero" (here, that colon is unnecessary, but whatever). $\quad$ On the other hand, if the full sentence is `∀a∈R:a≠0 P(a)` (this is a mix of formal and informal notation, and that colon means 'such that'), then it is equivalent to `∀a∈R (a≠0⟹P(a))` and means "every nonzero real $a$ has property P".

Comment: @AntonioDeAngelis P.S. That final grey box is equivalent to `∀a((a∈R and a≠0)⟹P(a))` and to `∀a∈R\{0} P(a)`. $\quad$ If you must use notation instead of words, I discourage against the first two grey boxes, while the the 3rd-5th grey boxes are all fine.

Comment: @ryang I see! Even more discrete in this case!

Answer (score 3):

I would write either $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ or integrate the $\neq 0$ part into the following, as in $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}: a\neq 0 \implies\ldots$.

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally write it as $\forall a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. Other forms might include "for all nonzero real $a$" and "$\forall a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a\neq0$".

Comment: I personally would refrain from $\mathbb{R} / \{0\}$ in lieu of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ (or even less annoyingly (IMO), $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$, $\mathbb{R}^\times$, or $\mathbb{R}_{\ne 0}$). The issue with the forward slash in $\mathbb{R} / \{0\}$ is that this is typically used to represent some kind of quotient structure (I've certainly never seen that slash used to represent set difference at least).

Comment: I'd edited the slash. Hopefully it is now more understandable.

Comment: I would not write "and" but "such that".